# Setting MTU does not work from systemd-networkd, but works from 'ip link set mtu'

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, network-interface, ip

I'm trying to change an `MTU` of an interface.
I've noticed it does not change correctly when using `systemd-networkd`, but it works when I use the `ip link set mtu` command.

Current `MTU` is 1500:

```
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 8 numrxqueues 8 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

Now, I changed my `/etc/systemd/network/50_eth0.network` file and added:

```
[Link]
MTUBytes = 1000
```

After `systemd-networkd` service restart, `syslog` shows:

```
Nov 30 23:36:20 me kernel: [84974.429088] igb 0000:00:14.0: changing MTU from 1500 to 1280
```

And current `MTU` is 1280:

```
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 8 numrxqueues 8 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

As you can see, I wanted 1000, but it changed to 1280. I think I read somewhere about a limit due to IPv6.

Now, when using the `ip` tool:

```
ip link set mtu 1000 dev eth0
```

`syslog`:

```
Nov 30 23:36:44 me kernel: [84998.785039] igb 0000:00:14.0: changing MTU from 1280 to 1000
```

And current `MTU` is 1000:

```
# ip -d link show dev eth0
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1000 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 numtxqueues 8 numrxqueues 8 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

Why does one way work and the other does not?
Thanks.

Comment: 1280 is the minimal MTU for IPv6. You could try and see if systemd will lower the MTU if you tell it to not use IPv6 (even if you already don't use it).

Comment: @A.B I will check, thanks.
But, when using `ip link set mtu`, does it automatically implies not to use IPv6 ?

Comment: `ip link` is a low level command. *systemd-networkd* is a higher level tool that might do its own interpretation of what to do. If it didn't use 1000 that's because it didn't "want" to use it, not because it couldn't.

Comment: If you use mtu 1000 and use IPv6 you are out of specs. Consider undefined behavior to happen, and no support for anything when asking because of using mtu 1000. So you should state in your question if you intend to use IPv6. Perhaps you should not write only those 2 lines of your setup, but the whole setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to A.B's comment.
Indeed, the `MTUBytes` of the `[Link]` section says this IPv6 note:

```
MTUBytes=
The maximum transmission unit in bytes to set for the device. The usual suffixes K, M, G, are supported and are understood to the base of 1024.
Note that if IPv6 is enabled on the interface, and the MTU is chosen below 1280 (the minimum MTU for IPv6) it will automatically be increased to this value.
```

After disabling IPv6 for that interface, I was able to have a lower MTU than 1280.
I've disabled that IPv6 for that interface using the below directive of the `[Network]` section, with the `none` value:

```
IPv6LinkLocalAddressGenerationMode=
Specifies how IPv6 link-local address is generated. Takes one of "eui64", "none", "stable-privacy" and "random". When unset, "stable-privacy" is used if IPv6StableSecretAddress= is specified, and if not, "eui64" is used. Note that if LinkLocalAddressing= is "no" or "ipv4", then IPv6LinkLocalAddressGenerationMode= will be ignored. Also, even if LinkLocalAddressing= is "yes" or "ipv6", setting IPv6LinkLocalAddressGenerationMode=none disables to configure an IPv6 link-local address.
```